# Monk and Swift Flight

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, flight

The monk power `Swift Flight` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13145)] states

> You fly a number of squares equal to your speed + your Wisdom modifier. If you don’t land at the end of this movement, you fall.

Can a monk fly these squares in arbitrary shape, as if he would walk them? Are there any special rules regarding flying? Can he fly a spiral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, he can.**

[Flying](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=367)<sup>DDI</sup> is a form of movement that leverage the fly speed, but is not limited to straight lines. In fact, you can take the walk, shift and running actions when flying.

> **FLIGHT**
>   Flight follows the basic movement rules, with the following clarifications.
>   **Fly Speed:** To fly, a creature takes the walk, run, or charge action but uses its fly speed in place of its walking speed. A creature that has a fly speed can also shift and take other move actions, as appropriate, while flying.
>   **Moving Up and Down:** While flying, a creature can move straight up, straight down, or diagonally up or down. There is no additional cost for moving up or down.
>   **Falling Prone:** If a creature falls prone while it is flying, it falls. This means a flying creature falls when it becomes unconscious or suffers any other effect that knocks it prone. The creature isn’t actually prone until it lands and takes falling damage.
>   **Remaining in the Air:** A flying creature does not need to take any particular action to remain aloft; the creature is assumed to be flying as it fights, moves, and takes other actions. However, a flying creature falls the instant it is stunned, unless it can hover.
>   **Landing:** If a creature flies to a surface it can hold onto or rest on, the creature can land safely.
>   **Terrain:** Terrain on the ground does not affect a flying creature if the terrain isn’t tall enough to reach it. Because of this rule, flying creatures can easily bypass typical difficult terrain, such as a patch of ice on the ground. Aerial terrain can affect flying creatures.

The term *falling* was previously defined as *crashing*.